# Determining size at which to switch from stack to heap allocation for multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, memory-management

I am developing a C++ library focused on multidimensional arrays and relevant operations involving these objects. The data for my "Tensor<T,n>" class (which corresponds to an n-dimensional array whose elements are of some numeric type T) is stored in a std::vector object and the elements are accessed via indices by calculating the appropriate index in the one-dimensional data vector using the concept of strides.

I understand that stack allocation is faster than heap allocation, and is generally safer. However, I also understand that heap allocation may be necessary for incredibly large data structures, and that users of this library may need to work with incredibly large data structures. My conclusion from this information is twofold:

1. for relatively small multidimensional arrays (in terms of number of elements), I should allocate this information on the stack.
2. for relatively large multidimensional arrays (in terms of number of elements), I should allocate this information on the heap.

I argue that this conclusion implies the existence of a "breaking point" as the size of a hypothetical array increases, at which I should switch from stack allocation to heap allocation. However, I have not been successful in finding resources that might assist me in determining where exactly this "breaking point" could be implemented to optimize efficiency for my user.

Assuming my conclusion is correct, how can I rigorously determine when to switch between the two types of allocation?

Comment: If you don't yet know all the ways that users will work with your library (and in general, you don't) then I don't think a rigorous answer should be your goal. I'd say make the value configurable, e.g. with a combination of compiler macro definition and static constant, and make an educated guess to supply it with a default value.

Comment: You are using std::vector for your data store, so you are already using the heap indirectly for the elements. (Ignoring small sizes where some vector implementations might have a small size optimization.)

Comment: And a threshold could well vary between different use cases, depending on how heavily they use your library & other stuff. You probably can't rigorously determine this in general. And it will change as computer systems change.

Comment: @AviBerger oops you are right. I think I'm in over my head here but at least I'm learning a lot. thanks for your help both of you

Comment: The "breaking point" depends on the host - available memory, how OS manages it, processes running, etc. On older hardware, heap and stack were physically distinct (different memory chips) and total stack for the machine rarely exceeded 1MB. But modern machines often have significant RAM, the OS uses virtual memory, so stack available to processes is set via quotas. Better to think about functional need to automatically/statically/dynamically manage objects, and use testing/profiling to identify and resolve any concerns. Otherwise, worrying about heap and stack is just premature optimisation.

Comment: If you really expect a lot of heap churn for what is actually stack-arranged data, you can expose a customizable allocation strategy that allows for this. For example a stack-like allocator with a configurable size that allocates once on the heap and then is used for all your stack stuff (including the `std::vector`). That gives you platform independence, provided there's enough heap memory available. It does get complicated quite fast though, so I'm inclined to be on the side of those who advise a rethink. _Definitely_ measure before committing. There are better places to improve performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `std::vector` has a constant size and allocates the actual data always on the heap. So no matter what matrix size you have the Matrix class will be constant size and always store data on the heap.

If you want a heap-free version then you would have to implement a Matrix with `std::array`. You could use `if constexpr` to choose between vector and array.

Note that heap allocation cost some time. But they also allow move semantic. The "break even" point might be as little as 4x4 matrixes but you have to test that. new/delete isn't that expensive if it can reuse memory and doesn't have to ask the kernel for more.

Oh, and there is also the option of using a custom allocator for the vector.